# Review my ruby for performance

Tags: ruby, mysql, ruby-on-rails

So I'm using the [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem to tag 3 different models: `Question`, `Blog`, and `Video`

Each one has a `site_id` to distinguish which site they show up on (SaaS-ish).

I wanted to get all tags for a specific site without saving `site_id` right on a `Tag` or `Tagging`.

I came up with the following, but I feel like there might be something more efficient I could do.

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def self.find_by_site site, limit=0
    klasses = [Blog, Question, Video]
    sql = []
    site_ids = []
    klasses.each do |k|
      sql << "
        SELECT tags.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taggings t WHERE t.tag_id = tags.id) AS `count`
              FROM tags
              LEFT JOIN taggings
              ON (taggings.tag_id = tags.id)
              LEFT JOIN #{k.table_name} 
              ON (#{k.table_name}.id = taggings.taggable_id)
              WHERE taggings.taggable_type = '#{k.name}'
              AND #{k.table_name}.site_id = ?
      "
    end
    sql = sql.join(" UNION ")
    sql += " GROUP BY id "
    sql += " ORDER BY COUNT DESC "
    sql += "LIMIT #{limit}" if limit > 0
    klasses.count.times { site_ids << site.id }
    find_by_sql([sql, *site_ids])
  end
end
```

Here is the current functionality with timing:

```
irb(main):011:0> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by_site Site.find(3); nil
  Site Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `sites`.* FROM `sites` WHERE `sites`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  
 SELECT tags.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taggings t WHERE t.tag_id = tags.id) AS `count`
 FROM tags
 LEFT JOIN taggings
 ON (taggings.tag_id = tags.id)
 LEFT JOIN blogs 
 ON (blogs.id = taggings.taggable_id)
 WHERE taggings.taggable_type = 'Blog'
 AND blogs.site_id = 3
 UNION 
 SELECT tags.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taggings t WHERE t.tag_id = tags.id) AS `count`
 FROM tags
 LEFT JOIN taggings
 ON (taggings.tag_id = tags.id)
 LEFT JOIN questions 
 ON (questions.id = taggings.taggable_id)
 WHERE taggings.taggable_type = 'Question'
 AND questions.site_id = 3
 UNION 
 SELECT tags.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taggings t WHERE t.tag_id = tags.id) AS `count`
 FROM tags
 LEFT JOIN taggings
 ON (taggings.tag_id = tags.id)
 LEFT JOIN videos 
 ON (videos.id = taggings.taggable_id)
 WHERE taggings.taggable_type = 'Video'
 AND videos.site_id = 3
 GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are all AR models with appropriate associations, I'd create a method on Site that iterates over a site instance's Blogs, Questions and Videos and collects their tags.  Something like this maybe:

```
def get_site_tags
  tags = []
  self.blogs.each do |blog|
    (tags <<  blog.tags)
  end
  self.questions.each do |question|
    (tags <<  question.tags)
  end
  self.videos.each do |video|
    (tags <<  video.tags)
  end
  tags.flatten!
end
```

Would this work for you or am I missing something?

Comment: The one I have now works, it just feels like it could be done with better performance. Your solution is very AR friendly, but has many trips to the database (each time `instance.tags` is called)

Comment: this should be a `map` instead of `each`